How to interpret being told that there are no current PhD openings but I should "keep in touch" for potential future opportunities?
A newly appointed professor in Computer Science from an European institution informed me that there is no available PhD position right now and suggested "keeping in touch as there could be potential opportunities in the future."
I'm extremely eager to seize this opportunity. How often should I check on the possible vacancy? What additional actions can I take in this regard?

From my experience as the one who is hiring, this is a polite yet very non-binding and rather "no" reply. This is a standard reply rather than an opportunity.
For me, if your CV looked super-valuable I'd:

have an online meeting with you to know you better
try to open a position from some extra funds (if this is CS and professor is good they often have some spare money to hire extra PhDs)
set a reminder for a next opening to inform you about position when it opens (if you are really good fit).

... otherwise I'd just reply: "keep in touch as there could be potential opportunities in the future."

I think it's just as likely that there is no position available and so the person contacted has not even seriously read their CV, because doing so would be a bit of a waste of their time given there is no position.

+1 for @BryanKrause's comment. #2 is harder than it seems and there are lots of other constraints too: office space, advisor's time/schedule/mental bandwidth, etc.  As for #3, some people might do so, but you'd need to make quite an impression. I'd expect most promising students to be snapped up within an application season or so, so it'd likely be a waste of time.

When I get an unexpected, exceptional candidate, I will do the following: (1) check with my post-award person to see if there is a way I can make it work (2) ask my Dean and VPR for an internal fellowship to make it happen (3) look for a co-PI whether for money or space issues (4) if I cannot have them, I refer them to my colleagues or top-level people I know at good places (people have sent me great students in the past, I am happy to send awesome students to them).... (5) if I say apply next cycle, it means I am just being polite mostly but would consider them under other circumstances.

This may be very dependent on the culture. In Central Europe, I would take such a statement at face value. On a subjective note, I see such answers as cowardly, misleading and non-educational regardless of cultural environment. “We regret to inform we don't have an opening for you” would be much more productive while remaining very polite.

@MrVocabulary What if the PI does want them, and wants them to stay in touch in case money became available?

@AzorAhai-him- That is exactly how I understand this message at face value. If it is anything else, then a different message should be uttered.

I hope that professors who say "keep in touch" when they actually mean "no" are not the same professors that complain about receiving too many emails...

@wimi ... There is definetly some overlap there.

If I'm not interested in a candidate I'll just say I've got no positions. The fact they want to stay in touch is encouraging. I can't invent positions when I don't have the funding yet.

You should interpret it as it states. For all practical purposes there are no current positions for you. Why? Because you are not as competitive as the people for which there are positions? Because there simply are no more slots available this cycle? Because the faculty is too polite to outright say no?
Who knows. For you, it means there are no positions regardless of the rationale. Perhaps next cycle there will be more options and you will be among the top of the cohort, so you should definitely apply if you are still on the market (this is true of any position, not just this one that this particular faculty communicated with you about).
What would I do with this information? Move on. Find somewhere else. You are best served just moving on and finding another place rather than waiting around for the stars to align.

This won't be quite so discouraging as the answer of Intelligent-infrastructure.
Don't wait around for something to develop with the professor. Pursue all other possibilities just as you would if you had not contacted them.
But, if nothing else develops for you in the meantime, contact them in the future with in enquiry and an updated CV. If their institution/group has regular admissions schedules, then sync your contact with that schedule, contacting them early in the next cycle. Otherwise, try again in a few (4-6) months and ask about opportunities.
The reason for just a bit of optimism is that a "new professor" may need some time to get set up to where they can take on students. But one of your other possibilities may bear fruit making contact unnecessary.

Very short answers to your questions:

How to interpret being told that there are no current PhD openings but I should "keep in touch" for potential future opportunities?

The only interpretation you can draw is that you applied when there is no opening.

How often should I check on the possible vacancy?

Regularly check openings in your field of interest, not just this particular one. Apply when you see an opportunity. Do not focus on this prof.

What additional actions can I take in this regard?

Treat this case as if you have never received a response.

Often taking a student is subject to grant funding. If I have no funding for additional students and I am busy, I may not carefully look at your CV and just tell you the truth: "I have no funding at this time, but may be interested in the future if I do obtain funding."
I also often receive emails from students who don't seem to have any idea of the kind of research that I do and don't seem to have a background appropriate for this research. I'm more likely to dismiss these emails out of hand (just delete them or give them a very quick response). Did you make clear that you are interested in a particular aspect of this professor's research and make clear that you have a background that would be useful in their research field? Unfortunately, you may need to make your email stand out from the spam.

To answer the second of your questions: If you are really keen to work for this specific professor, keep checking back for job ads every month or so. At least in Germany, universities did not have fixed "hiring cycles", but professors would post job ads as funding became available - unless, of course, they already had a candidate lined up for the position, in which case it would be filled without ever being posted.
And to answer the third of your questions: There really isn't much you can do except wait. There is no position now, and most (german) professors I have met would post any openings online if they were able to hire a new PhD student, but were not able to "create a position" if they did not have funding readily available (or at least, they wouldn't be willing to do this for a "random" applicant, but only for a really good student they already knew).
I agree with the others, that this reply is rather boilerplate and does not mean that there is an opportunity for you to seize or that a/the vacancy will be published any time soon, and that it's best to not focus on this specific place, but to start looking for other options.

The email is a cue to move on.
This professor presumably knows the institutional or agency deadlines for funding and the admission landscape so if they were interested they should have been explicit about the timescale, i.e. something like “I don’t have funding or space for another student right now but if you get back to me in a couple of months the situation may have changed”.
It is also IMO telling that this person did not suggest you apply for admission.  Something like “I encourage your to apply as this could lead to funding opportunities” would be more hopeful that the boiler-plate reply you have received.
